# How use more than one value for attribute in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I want to use more than one value for the attribute in XSLT.

Input:

```
<contrib contrib-type="author">
     <name>
         <surname>Khorana</surname>
         <given-names>Alok A.</given-names>
     </name>
     <degrees>MD</degrees>
</contrib>
<contrib contrib-type="author">
     <name>
         <surname>Holand</surname>
         <given-names>Gamak J.</given-names>
     </name>
     <degrees>PhD</degrees>
</contrib>
```

The output should be:

```
<fieldSet name="Author" value="Alok A. Khorana, MD Gamak J. Holand, PhD"/>
```

Tried code:

```
<xsl:template name="take-author">
    <tps:fieldSet name="Author">
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(descendant::contrib[@contrib-type='author']/name/given-names,descendant::contrib[@contrib-type='author']/name/surname)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </tps:fieldSet>
</xsl:template>
```

But I am getting the following error when trying the above code

> A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument
>   of concat()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact you get that message suggests you are using XSLT 2.0, which does not allow a sequence of more than one element as parameter to a function that expects a string argument.

If indeed you are using XSLT 2.0 (or above) you can do this...

```
<xsl:value-of select="descendant::contrib[@contrib-type='author']/concat(name/given-names, ' ', name/surname, ', ', degrees)" separator=" " />
```

(Note, the default separator is space anyway, so in this case you could omit the separator attribute, but I left it in just to demonstrate its use).

Also note, in XSLT 1.0, `xsl:value-of` will only return the value of the first node in a node-set, so you would have to write it like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="descendant::contrib[@contrib-type='author']">
    <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:text> </xsl:text></xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(name/given-names, ' ', name/surname, ', ', degrees)" />
</xsl:for-each>
```